# Drop down is not rendering when I use rc-tree-select component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I have below component where I am trying to render a TreeSelect component.

```
import 'rc-tree-select/assets/index.less';
import TreeSelect from 'rc-tree-select';


function App() {

  const data = [{
    label: 'search me',
    value: 'searchme',

  }]
  return (

    <div>
      Tree select demo
      <TreeSelect treeData={data} style={{ width: '300px' }} placeholder="select" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am not able to render  the dropdown  properly with above code as you can see from attached screenshot. What I am doing wrong here. Can someone please help

[image]